# Wagtail Search in CMS

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I'm trying to search through all of my pages on the backend to find instances of urls with outdated domain names. But when I search, it only seems to get hits based on the title of the pages, and not their content. Is there something I need to configure to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To search on fields beyond the ones that are common to all page types (such as title), you'll need to [define a `search_fields` property](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/search/indexing.html#indexing-extra-fields) on your page model, such as:

```
from wagtail.search import index

class MyPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(...)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('body')
    ]
```

After setting this up, you'll need to update the search index to contain this new data, by running `./manage.py update_index`.

If you're running 2.14.x or earlier, you'll also need to set up an alternative search backend such as Postgres or Elasticsearch - [the default `wagtail.search.backends.db` search backend](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.14.2/topics/search/backends.html#database-backend-default) was very limited and only supported searching on the 'core' fields such as title. As of 2.15, [a new `wagtail.search.backends.database` backend](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/releases/2.15.html#database-search-backends-replaced) is available and enabled on new projects out of the box, and this has full support for searching across all fields.